# What qualifies an Android "Display"?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, display-manager

In API 17, Android introduced the ability to present content on secondary displays.  They say that content can be shown on any display that is connected to the device by either a wired connection or WiFi.  You can even get the list of connected displays with the `DisplayManager` class.  What I want to know is, what qualifies an Android "display"?  What types of devices can I use as secondary displays using the `DisplayManager` class?

API 17 Link:http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html
DisplayManager:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want to know is, what qualifies an Android "display"? What types of devices can I use as secondary displays using the DisplayManager class?

That is up to the device manufacturer. Some devices support HDMI-out, via some sort of connector (micro HDMI, MHL, etc.). Some devices support Miracast. And so on. From the standpoint of Android, they will appear to be a monitor. Whether they are an LCD monitor or a TV or an HDMI recorder or something else is up to the manufacturer of that equipment.

Note that not all devices that have Android 4.2 and support an external display will support `Presentation` for those external displays. For example:

- the Nexus 4 supports `Presentation` via Miracast
- the Nexus 10 supports `Presentation` via HDMI
- the Galaxy Nexus, at present, does not support `Presentation` via MHL
- the ASUS Transformer Infinity, at present, does not support `Presentation` via HDMI

Comment: Is there a list or documentation out there of current Android displays?

Comment: @crocboy: Every monitor with HDMI input is a valid display for compatible Android devices. Every television with HDMI input is a valid display for compatible Android devices. Every projector with HDMI input is a valid display for compatible Android devices. This list would be thousands of entries long.

Comment: I understand wired displays, but what wireless protocols are supported?

Comment: Yes, but are there any others?

Comment: @crocboy: If there were others supported by Android, I would have mentioned them. There might be others supported in the future, either by individual device manufacturers or Android proper.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it possible to cast screen from one Mobile device (nexus 5 ) to another mobile device such as Nexus 7, were both the device has Miracast feature? 
Or  it can only support displaying on dedicated display device like smart TVs ?

Comment: @Pravy: "Is it possible to cast screen from one Mobile device... to another mobile device" -- not usually. I can't rule out some manufacturer turning their device into a Miracast receiver, but I have never seen any, and the Nexus 7 certainly does not offer that.